# I need help for woocommerce integration in google sheet through web hook

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce

I just attach my woocommerce through webhook in google sheet and get some code from internet for getting orders data on it every things looks fine but there is only one product name available even if the order contain more than one products.You can check the webhook data [here](https://pastebin.com/WX3iSeHN) when order is created. here is my google sheet script code

```
    //this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_created      = myData.date_created;
  var product_name       = myData.line_items[0].name;
  var itemName = myData.line_items[0].name;
  var quantity = myData.line_items[0].quantity;
  var product_items      = quantity + " x " + itemName + "\n"; 
  var product_qty        = myData.line_items[0].quantity;
  var order_total        = myData.total;
  var billing_email      = myData.billing.email;
  var billing_first_name = myData.billing.first_name;
  var billing_phone      = myData.billing.phone;
  var shipping_address   = myData.shipping.address_1;

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([timestamp,order_created,billing_first_name,billing_phone,shipping_address,product_name,product_qty,order_total,billing_email,product_items]);
}
```

Comment: You ahve this line var product_name       = myData.line_items[0].name; so it looks myData.line_items is an array with the lines of the order. So you must loop into this array to store all the line in the sheets. When you enter myData.line_items[0] you get the data for the first line only, that is why you have only one product as you said in the question.

Comment: Yeah that's right i try to add a loop in line_items but than it generate two lines i need only one line which contains both products name.

Comment: Please edit your answer to display the value of `myData`. Without that information, both you and we are just shooting in the dark.

Comment: ok i added the link for the data you can check the webhook data that will assign to mydata https://pastebin.com/WX3iSeHN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop through sone JSON transaction data that includes multiple line items.

There are two flaws in your code:

1 - the script does not loop through the product items:

  `var product_name = myData.line_items[0].name;
  var itemName = myData.line_items[0].name;
  var quantity = myData.line_items[0].quantity;
  var product_items = quantity + " x " + itemName + "\n"; 
  var product_qty = myData.line_items[0].quantity;`

You are getting line_items[0], but if there are multiple line items in the transaction then you are only ever returning the first line item.

2 - The variables being appended in `sheet.appendRow()` need to be re-considered.

Your code specifies ten variables, including `product name` and `product quantity`. However there are no unique values for these two variables since they are form part of the line items and vary with each line item in the transaction.

Your variable `product_items` is an attempt to recognise this by concatenating the details for each line item; however the variable fails because it depends on looping through the line_items AND progressively concatenating line item values.

The following code is an example of how you might achieve your outcome:

---

```
function doPost(e) {
var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var order_created = myData.date_created; 
  var billing_first_name = myData.billing.first_name;
  var billing_phone = myData.billing.phone;
  var billing_email = myData.billing.email;
  var shipping_address = myData.shipping.address_1;
  var order_total = myData.total;

  var lineitems=""
  for (i in myData.line_items)
  {
    var product_name       = myData.line_items[i].name;
    var itemName = myData.line_items[i].name;
    var quantity = myData.line_items[i].quantity;
    var linetotal = myData.line_items[i].total;
    var product_items      = quantity + " x " + itemName + ":$"+linetotal +"\n"; 
    var lineitems =lineitems+product_items;
  }

  Logger.log("Timestamp: "+timestamp);
  Logger.log("Order created: "+order_created);
  Logger.log("Billing first name: "+billing_first_name+", Phone: "+billing_phone+", Email: "+billing_email);
  Logger.log("Shipping Address: "+shipping_address)
  Logger.log("Line items = "+lineitems);
  Logger.log("Order Total: "+order_total)
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([timestamp,order_created,billing_first_name,billing_phone,shipping_address,order_total,billing_email,lineitems]);
}
```